# How to reference a child class in parent @classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have the following code to find instances of objects in a database and then create python objects with the data.

```
class Parent:
    @staticmethod
    def get(table, **kwargs):
        """retrieves a register in the DB given the kwargs"""
        return get_from_db(table, **kwargs)

class ChildA(Parent):
    _table = 'table_child_a'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """adds the arguments retrieved in the DB"""
        for k, v in attributes.items():
            setattribute(self, k, v)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, **kwargs):
        """retrieves the data from the db and creates a ChildA object with it"""
        return ChildA(attributes=Parent.get(cls._table, **kwargs))

class ChildB(Parent):
    _table = 'table_child_b'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """adds the arguments retrieved in the DB"""
        for k, v in attributes.items():
            setattribute(self, k, v)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, **kwargs):
        """retrieves the data from the db and creates a ChildB object with it"""
        return ChildB(attributes=Parent.get(cls._table, **kwargs))
```

Is it possible to implement the Children get method in the Parent (so I don't have to implement it every time I create a Child class), but to know what kind of Children to return (please, bear in mind that it must be a class/static method.

Comment: Given that a classmethod receives a class argument, knowing which child to return is trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to rename one of them (can't have two methods named `get`). Looking at it, there's no real reason to have a `Parent.get` that just wraps `get_from_db`. 
The identical `__init__` methods could also go in `Parent`

```
def get_from_db(table, **kwargs): # Just for illustration
    print(table)
    return {}

class Parent:  
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, **kwargs):
        """retrieves the data from the db and creates a Parent subclass object with it"""
        return cls(attributes=get_from_db(cls._table, **kwargs))
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """adds the arguments retrieved in the DB"""
        for k, v in kwargs['attributes'].items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

class ChildA(Parent):
    _table = 'table_child_a'

class ChildB(Parent):
    _table = 'table_child_b'

print(ChildA.get())

# table_child_a
# <__main__.ChildA object at 0x7ff9be8aa5f8>
```

Comment: It worked, it was way easier than what I thought, thank you!