# How to correctly define a classmethod that accesses a value of a mangled child attribute?

Tags: python, enums, python-class

In Python, how do I correctly define a classmethod of a parent class that references an attribute of a child class?

```py
from enum import Enum


class LabelledEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def list_labels(cls):
        return list(l for c, l in cls.__labels.items())


class Test(LabelledEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3

    __labels = {
        1: "Label A",
        2: "Custom B",
        3: "Custom label for value C + another string",
    }


print(Test.list_labels())
# expected output
# ["Label A", "Custom B", "Custom label for value C + another string"]
```

In the code above I expect that `Test.list_labels()` will correctly print out the labels, however because the `__labels` dictionary is defined with the double underscore, I cannot access it correctly.

The reason I wanted to have double underscore is to make sure that the labels would not show up when iterating over the enumerator, e.g. list(Test) should not show the dictionary containing labels.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga agree, but it's not that straight forward when it comes to Enum. From the documentation: *"Private names are not converted to enum members, but remain normal attributes."* -- Which is what the OP is after.

Comment: You could do something really ugly like `getattribute(cls, f"_{cls.__name__}__labels", {})`, not sure if it's guaranteed to work in every situation.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: thank you, yes, I've seen variations of this question for classes that do not inherit from Enum (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49503062/10693596), but I'm wondering about the Enum case... I do realise I might be going down the completely wrong path on this one.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: the "ugly" solution is good enough for my use case. Can you post it as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: This answer was originally a comment to the question.
>
> **I strongly advise taking a different approach, like:**
>
> - [Ethan Furman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77817668/1241334) (author of Python's `Enum`)
> - Or [juanpa.arrivillaga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77817412/1241334)

---

##### Python 3.11+

I do not suggest using private names. That being said, if for some reason you must use private names and you can't use the [`@enum.nonmember`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/enum.html#enum.nonmember) decorator, which is a much better approach. Then the following will work in Python 3.11+.

The `_Private__names` section in [Enum HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#private-names) states:

> [Private names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#private-name-mangling) are not converted to enum members, but remain normal attributes.

You could do something really ugly like:

```python
getattr(cls, f"_{cls.__name__}__labels", {})
```

```python
from enum import Enum

class LabelledEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def list_labels(cls):
        # account for private name mangling
        labels = getattr(cls, f"_{cls.__name__}__labels", {})
        return list(l for c, l in labels.items())

class Test(LabelledEnum):
    A = 1
    __labels = { 1: "Label A" }


print(Test.list_labels())
# ['Label A']
```

---

##### Python < 3.11

In Python versions less than 3.11, `__labels` will become the `_Test__labels` enum member of `Test`. And the above code will raise an error, due to `getattr` returning the enum rather than a `dict`.

```python
print(Test.__members__)
#{'A': <Test.A: 1>, '_Test__labels': <Test._Test__labels: {1: 'Label A'}>}

print(type(Test._Test__labels))
#<enum 'Test'>
```

Also, in Python 3.9 and 3.10, using private names in an enum class will cause a `DeprecationWarning`, similar to the following:

```text
DeprecationWarning: private variables, such as '_Test__labels', will be normal attributes in 3.10
```

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should...

Comment: @MatBailie I agree, edited my answer to (hopefully) reflect that sentiment. I was unaware of `@enum.nonmember` and there is no mention of it in [Enum HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html), only the [private names](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#private-names) section. I endorsed another answer to be accepted [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77817356/how-to-correctly-define-a-classmethod-that-accesses-a-value-of-a-mangled-child-a/77817418?noredirect=1#comment137186588_77817412).

Answer (score 4):

While the `getattr` method works, a more elegant solution is to make `LabelledEnum` a mix-in instead, and define the label with the value:

```
from enum import Enum

class LabelledEnumMixin:

    labels = {}

    def __new__(cls, value, label):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.label = label
        cls.labels[value] = label
        return member

    @classmethod
    def list_labels(cls):
        return list(l for c, l in cls.labels.items())


class Test(LabelledEnumMixin, Enum):
    A = 1, "Label A"
    B = 2, "Custom B"
    C = 3, "Custom label for value C + another string"
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Thank you, I tried getting the mixin method working on my own and failed. This looks great!

Comment: Wow. With this unexpected answer I've dug up the source code to find that a tuple value is [special-cased](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1709020e8ebaf9bf1bc9ee14d56173c860613931/Lib/enum.py#L256) so that it can be [unpacked](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1709020e8ebaf9bf1bc9ee14d56173c860613931/Lib/enum.py#L262) as arguments to the constructor of the member's type. How can such an important feature be undocumented? Please make this behavior a publicly documented feature so we won't have to fear using what would currently be considered an implementation detail. Thanks!

Comment: Added a [request](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/114071) for documentation in the Python issue tracker. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet, if you are on Python >= 3.11 is to use `enum.nonmember` and a *single underscore*:

```
In [8]: import enum
   ...:
   ...: class LabelledEnum(enum.Enum):
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def list_labels(cls):
   ...:         return list(l for c, l in cls._labels.items())
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: class Test(LabelledEnum):
   ...:     A = 1
   ...:     B = 2
   ...:     C = 3
   ...:
   ...:     _labels = enum.nonmember({
   ...:         1: "Label A",
   ...:         2: "Custom B",
   ...:         3: "Custom label for value C + another string",
   ...:     })
   ...:

In [9]: list(Test)
Out[9]: [<Test.A: 1>, <Test.B: 2>, <Test.C: 3>]

In [10]: Test.list_labels()
Out[10]: ['Label A', 'Custom B', 'Custom label for value C + another string']
```

If you are working with at least Python 3.7, you can use enum specific "sunder" names, and add `"_lables"` to the ignore list:

```
class Test(LabelledEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    _ignore_ = ["_labels"]
    _labels = {
        1: "Label A",
        2: "Custom B",
        3: "Custom label for value C + another string",
    }
```


The other approach is to  build up the string dynamically, which is quite clunky, although, it would work (frankly, `enum` should be ignoring *single* underscores, not double, but alas):

```
@classmethod
def list_labels(cls):
    labels = getattr(cls, f"_{cls.__name__}__labels"
    return list(labels.values())
```

Comment: thank you, I really like enum.nonmember!

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev you can also use `_ignore_` in versions greater than 3.7

Comment: I would accept this answer, it's better. I was looking for `nonmember` in Enum's documentation but couldn't find it.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: yes, but I felt bad since I already promised to accept yours. :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: and here I was thinking I new enough about enums... Thank you very much again!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not sure if `_ignore_` is a viable option. The documentation states: *"`_ignore_` – a list of names, either as a `list` or a `str`, that will not be transformed into members, **and will be removed from the final class**."* Which makes it seem like `_labels` won't be an enum member of `Test`, but it also won't be an attribute of the `Test` class returned by `Enum`'s meta class's `__new__`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly yup!